# Oracle How to alter table date format to Month5

Tags: oracle

I'm inserting date in the Month format from other Data Analytics Language into the ORACLE Version 17.2.

Date is in the Month Format Month5. (like DEC19,JAN20,So on....).

My Table in Oracle which should get fill with these values is in the DATE format, I'm aware about TIMESTAMP format. DATE format in ORALCE restrict insert operations of values in Month format Month5..

Hence i would like to know the MONTHYY format i can alter my table in ORACLE.

Thanks......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TO_DATE` as following:

```
TO_DATE('<Your_value>', 'MONRR')
```

So for sample values from the question it will be like:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      TO_DATE('DEC19', 'MONRR') VAL1,
>   3      TO_DATE('JAN20', 'MONRR') VAL2
>   4  FROM
>   5      DUAL;
>
> VAL1        VAL2
> ----------- -----------
> 01-DEC-2019 01-JAN-2020
> ```

Please note that

- If you skip the date(day) in the `TO_DATE` function it will be defaulted to **1st day of the month**
- If you skip the month, it will be considered as the **current month**.
- If you skip the year then it will be considered as the **current year**.

.

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      TO_DATE('01JAN', 'DDMON') AS YR, --year skipped
>   3      TO_DATE('012012', 'DDYYYY') AS MON,  -- month skipped
>   4      TO_DATE('FEB2012', 'MONYYYY') AS DY -- date(day) skipped
>   5  FROM
>   6      DUAL;
>
> YR          MON         DY
> ----------- ----------- -----------
> 01-JAN-2020 01-JAN-2012 01-FEB-2012
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Better use format `'MONRR'` in order to have "higher probability" for guessing correct year. And you should include parameter `'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'`

Comment: Perfect!! Done. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Tejash, I believe if you skip the month, it will default to current month.

Comment: Ohh, Yes @Slkrasnodar. mistakenly wrote that. Corrected now!!